# EPPLUS throwing exception while using worksheet.Insertrow(int rowfrom, int rows, int startrowfrom) in .net core 3.1 app

Tags: .net-core-3.1

I am developing an webapp using .net core 3.1 and I am getting some EPPLUS EXCEPTION like "Invalid Address format APPID".
here is my error log:

```
2020-07-08T13:13:25.9386149-04:00 0HM13C84RA267:00000002 [ERR] Invalid Address format APPID (5598a7b8)
2020-07-08T13:13:26.3540346-04:00 0HM13C84RA267:00000002 [ERR]    at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellBase.ThrowAddressException(String address, Int32& row, Int32& col, Boolean throwException)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellBase.GetRowCol(String address, Int32& row, Int32& col, Boolean throwException, Boolean& fixedRow, Boolean& fixedCol)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellBase.GetRowColFromAddress(String CellAddress, Int32& FromRow, Int32& FromColumn, Int32& ToRow, Int32& ToColumn, Boolean& fixedFromRow, Boolean& fixedFromColumn, Boolean& fixedToRow, Boolean& fixedToColumn)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelAddressBase.SetAddress(String address)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelNamedRangeCollection.Insert(Int32 rowFrom, Int32 colFrom, Int32 rows, Int32 cols, Func`2 filter, Int32 lowerLimint, Int32 upperLimit)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelNamedRangeCollection.Insert(Int32 rowFrom, Int32 colFrom, Int32 rows, Int32 cols, Int32 lowerLimint, Int32 upperLimit)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Core.Worksheet.WorksheetRangeInsertHelper.InsertCellStores(ExcelWorksheet ws, Int32 rowFrom, Int32 columnFrom, Int32 rows, Int32 columns, Int32 columnTo)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Core.Worksheet.WorksheetRangeInsertHelper.InsertRow(ExcelWorksheet ws, Int32 rowFrom, Int32 rows, Int32 copyStylesFromRow)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.InsertRow(Int32 rowFrom, Int32 rows, Int32 copyStylesFromRow)
   at Api.Utility.ExcelHelper.abc(String templatePath, String targetFile, List`1 lstSmallDollarWriteoff, String userId, String userName, String monthYearFolder, Int64 eventLogId)
```

my code is like below :

```
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(targetFile), new FileInfo(templatePath)))
            {                
                int startRow = 13;
                int counter = 1;
                ExcelWorksheet objWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Journal Entry"];
                //Posting date
                objWorksheet.Cells[8, 2].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                var lstGroup = lstdata.GroupBy(x => new { x.Company, x.Currency, x.Division }).
                Select(x => new { x.Key, Amount = x.Sum(y => y.Amount) });
                int rows = lstdata.Count + lstGroup.Count();
                int rowFrom=(startRow + 1);

                objWorksheet.InsertRow( rowFrom, rows, startRow); //Here, for executing this, I am getting the exception
                foreach (var item in lstGroup)
                {
                    List<SettleData> lstSDataByKey = lstDataByKey.Where(x => x.Division == item.Key.Division && x.Company == item.Key.Company && x.Currency == item.Key.Currency).ToList();
                    foreach (SettleData keyItem in lstDataByKey)
                    {
                        CreateJetsEntry(ref startRow, ref counter, objWorksheet, keyItem);
                    }
                }
                excelPackage.Save();
            }
        }
```

I have used EPPLUS in my appsettings.json like below :

```
"EPPlus": {
    "ExcelPackage": {
        "LicenseContext": "Commercial" 
        }
    },
```

Any leads will be appreciated. I am stuck in this for a while.

Comment: That's rather convoluted code. Epplus allows you to load a collection, DataTable or DbDataReader directly into a region. If you perform any transformations *before* inserting anything to the sheet, eg with one LINQ query instead of loops, you could load all the data with a single `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I get your point.but i need to use in this way only and do you have any idea why i am getting such exception? i have another app using .net core 2.0 with similar code, and there it does work.

Comment: I updetd the EPLUS version to "4.5.3.2" in my api.csproj and it worked ! I dont know whether there exists such dependency but it worked...